# No handlers could be found for logger "bs4.dammit"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I write a small link miner by using `BeautifulSoup` library.
But I saw that there was some link that doesn't handled. So I test one of theme:

```
result = requests.get('https://domain.ir/PATH_TO_FILE/optics-program-msc.pdf')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content,'html.parser')
f2.write('{"counter":'+str(i)+', "id": "'+a['href']+'", "group":'+str(counter)+", \"children\":"+str(len(soup.find_all('a',href=True)))+"},\n")
```

I understood that `html.parser` cannot handle all links and I give this error

> No handlers could be found for logger "bs4.dammit"

So the link doesn't written in file. But There is some links that I don't no which parser should be use. like `.pdf,.zip,...`.
So what should I do?

Comment: `html.parser` parses HTML, but that file is clearly PDF. BeautifulSoup was created to work with HTML and XML, not other file types.

Comment: @ForceBru Tnx, I know. my problem is that this error cause that the link doesn't written in file.

Comment: I have used PyMuPDF to glean images from PDFs. I haven't tried to ferret out links though. You could still take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all: you should use `result.text`, because it is already unicode string (instead of bytes in `content`)
- Second thing to check: is it really parsed "soup" of HTML with links? By putting one simple `if soup.body:`
- The third one: `bs4.dummit` warning says about problem with detecting encoding, so try put some more info about it: `BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="windows-1259")`
- Another one: instead of `html.parser`, try to use `lxml`